# Unexpected token error when I have the variable already defined

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

Simple script but can't figure out why I am getting the error :   It should just write the machines that were successful to one text file and the failed to another.

Here is the error I am getting :

Unexpected token '$ip' in expression or statement.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnexpectedToken

```
$computers = Get-Content C:\temp\machines_no_rdp.txt

foreach($computer in $computers)

 {


  if((New-Object System.Net.NetworkInformation.Ping).Send("$computer",[int]1000).Address.IPAddressToString)

   {

    $computer
   $ip = [System.Net.Dns]::GetHostByName($computer).AddressList.IPAddressToString



    $computer + ";" $ip | Out-File C:\temp\Success.txt -Append

   }

    else{$computer + ";" + "Dead" | Out-File C:\temp\failure.txt -Append}

   }
```

Comment: This is just a missing `+`. `$computer + ";" $ip` should be `$computer + ";"  + $ip` or many other string concatenation solutions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is trying to tell you it does know what to do with `$ip`. It does not care at this point whether it is a variable or not. It's a parsing error.

```
$computer + ";" $ip
```

should instead be the following ( in keeping with your coding practice.)

```
$computer + ";" + $ip
```